# What type of integral am I dealing with?

Tags: calculus, integration

Please can someone clarify for me what the type of integral following is called?  I find confusing references to it as 'contour', 'surface', 'curvilinear' etc.

$\frac{1}{2}\oint_\gamma x\,dy-y\,dx$

The connected question therefore is what is $\gamma$?  Is it a 'contour', 'surface',  'domain', 'region' etc.?

Grateful for the clarification - will help me no end finding the correct material for my studies.

Comment: In the language of forms, it is an integral of a one form over a loop. In the language of vector calculus, it's the integral over a vector field over a loop. Suppose we have a paramterization, then $ dy = v_y dt$ and $dx = v_x dt$. SO, we have:

$$ \oint_{\gamma} [ x v_y - y v_x ] dt= \oint (v_x , v_y) \cdot (-y,x) dt$$

To avoid confusion the vector field is $(-y,x)$ and $(v_x,v_y)$ is the tangent vector

Comment: Thanks very much for such a quick response.  So are the names of the integral I have come across just related to specific examples or are there other names in other areas of maths?

Comment: I guess some would call this the area of a loop integral (you get area of the loop you integrate over as a result of this)

Comment: Line integral over closed curve, contour integral over closed curve

Comment: Thanks @IvanKaznacheyeu.